# Insertar carácter en json con Powershell

Tags: json, insert, powershell

Estoy tratando de insertar un carácter al final de un string en un json con powershell pero no lo consigo.

Concretamente, intento añadir la `Z` al final del campo `fecha` haciendo esto:

`$S4=$S3.Insert($S3.IndexOf("2020T")+8,"Z") $S4`

El script Powershel completo en el que formateo la salida como la necesito:

```
$S1 = [io.file]::readalltext(“C:\Temp\aoutcsv.json”).replace(": ","=")
$S2=$S1.replace(""",","""")
$S3 =$S2.replace("/2020 ","/2020T")
**$S4=$S3.Insert($S3.IndexOf("2020T")+8,"Z")
$S4**
```

JSON original:

```
[
    {
        "id"= "5406678307",
        "fecha"= "02/04/2020 9:33:19",
        "estado_id"= "3",
        "id2"= "252",
        "usr_l1"= "12306",
        "motivo_estado_id"= "",
        "usr_l2"= "413283",
        "cambio_grupo"= "False",
        "estado_fix"= "0"
    },
    {
        "id"= "540633678307",
        "fecha"= "02/04/2020 9:32:53",
        "estado_id"= "3",
        "id2"= "247",
        "usr_l1"= "",
        "motivo_estado_id"= "",
        "usr_l2"= "2323112",
        "cambio_grupo"= "True",
        "estado_fix"= "0"
    }]
```

JSON como lo necesitaria recibir (con las `Z` en los campos fecha):

```
[{
        "id"= "5406678307"
        "fecha"= "02/04/2020T9:33:19Z"
        "estado_id"= "3"
        "id2"= "252"
        "usr_l1"= "12306"
        "motivo_estado_id"= ""
        "usr_l2"= "413283"
        "cambio_grupo"= "False"
        "estado_fix"= "0"
    },
    {
        "id"= "540633678307"
        "fecha"= "02/04/2020T9:32:53Z"
        "estado_id"= "3"
        "id2"= "247"
        "usr_l1"= ""
        "motivo_estado_id"= ""
        "usr_l2"= "2323112"
        "cambio_grupo"= "True"
        "estado_fix"= "0"
    }]
```

me he estado peleando pero no lo consigo. ¿Me podéis echar una mano? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes indicar cuál es el codigo que has utilizado para añadirlo?

Comment: Intento añadir la Z al final del campo fecha haciendo esto: $S4=$S3.Insert($S3.IndexOf("2020T")+8,"Z")
$S4

Comment: `$S3.IndexOf("2020T")+8`, sólo cogerá la primera aparición. En efecto sólo te está modificando uno quizá?

Comment: Ni si quiera me lo añade pero si le pongo el string completo si me lo hace, es decir, si lo pongo así :
$S4=$S3.Insert($S3.IndexOf("02/04/2020T9:32:53")+18,"Z") 
$S4
Si me lo pondría en el formato que necesito:
 "02/04/2020T9:32:53Z"
Pero claro solo me lo haría en ese registro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu aproximación realizando sustituciones de texto, puede volverse muy compleja.

En mi caso, he utilizado unos [JSON CMDlets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7) que permiten manejar los campos directos del JSON, en vez de tener que hacer sustituciones de texto, por lo que resulta más fácil.

> Por otra parte, en vez de buscar `2020` para incluir la `T`, verás que
>   busco el espacio, de modo que el script seguirá valiendo más allá del
>   año 2020.

El resultado final es el mismo, por lo que entiendo que resolverá tu problema.

script.ps1

```
# Usando utilidades Json

#Primero guardamos la variable del texto
$S1 =  [io.file]::readalltext(“test.json”)

#Y la convertimos a JSON. Importante poner los paréntesis para que realmente se guarde como un Array.
$S2 =  ($S1 | ConvertFrom-JSON )

#Utilizamos el bucle for para recorrerlo
for ($i=0; $i -lt $S2.count; $i++)
{
   #Y ahora podemos acceder a los campos sin problema y modificarlos.
   #Modifico primero un espacio por la T
   $S2[$i].fecha = $S2[$i].fecha.replace(" ","T")
   #Y luego añado la Z al final
   $S2[$i].fecha = $S2[$i].fecha + "Z"
   $S2[$i].fecha
}

#Puedes imprimirlo como matriz de datos

$S2

#O Puedes volver a convertirlo a String 

$Stext =  ($S2 | ConvertTo-JSON )


$Stext



PS C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents>
```

Resultado:

```
PS C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents> C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\script.ps1
02/04/2020T9:33:19Z
02/04/2020T9:32:53Z


id               : 5406678307
fecha            : 02/04/2020T9:33:19Z
estado_id        : 3
id2              : 252
usr_l1           : 12306
motivo_estado_id : 
usr_l2           : 413283
cambio_grupo     : False
estado_fix       : 0

id               : 540633678307
fecha            : 02/04/2020T9:32:53Z
estado_id        : 3
id2              : 247
usr_l1           : 
motivo_estado_id : 
usr_l2           : 2323112
cambio_grupo     : True
estado_fix       : 0

[
    {
        "id":  "5406678307",
        "fecha":  "02/04/2020T9:33:19Z",
        "estado_id":  "3",
        "id2":  "252",
        "usr_l1":  "12306",
        "motivo_estado_id":  "",
        "usr_l2":  "413283",
        "cambio_grupo":  "False",
        "estado_fix":  "0"
    },
    {
        "id":  "540633678307",
        "fecha":  "02/04/2020T9:32:53Z",
        "estado_id":  "3",
        "id2":  "247",
        "usr_l1":  "",
        "motivo_estado_id":  "",
        "usr_l2":  "2323112",
        "cambio_grupo":  "True",
        "estado_fix":  "0"
    }
]
```

Comment: Creo que esto me puede valer Alejandro, lo pruebo y comento.Gracias

Comment: Perfecto. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Me alegro!!! Yo tbn he aprendido un poquito!!! :) Así que me alegro que te haya funcionado!!