# Powershell para modificar el formato fecha en un json

Tags: json, datetime, powershell, date-format

Referente al [articulo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/344059/insertar-car%C3%A1cter-en-json-con-powershell)  que cree pero no me deja seguir escribiendo ahí y que me resolvió [Alejandro Teixeira](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16285/alejandro-teixeira-mu%C3%B1oz) ,me encuentro con otro problema.
Para poner en antecedentes, lo que esto haciendo es formatear un json que me viene de una bbdd para poder hacer un push a la api de powerBI.
Para ello el formato del JSON tiene que ser el siguiente:

```
{
"fecha" ="2020-04-29T13:53:34.561Z"
"estado_id" ="AAAAA555555"
"COUNT(incidencia_id)" =98.6
}
```

El json que me tengo ya "pre-cocinado" es el siguiente:

```
{
        "fecha"= "29-04-2020T14:33:22.175Z"
        "estado_id"= "8"
        "COUNT(incidencia_id)"= 152
    }
```

Como veis el formato de fecha no es el mismo y es lo que trato de modificar pero no se como...

El powershell que estoy usando para precocinarlo es el siguiente:

```
import-csv "C:\Temp\outcsv.csv" | ConvertTo-Json > C:\Temp\aoutcsv.json



#Primero guardamos en variable como texto
$S1 =  [io.file]::readalltext(“C:\Temp\aoutcsv.json”)

#Y la convertimos a JSON.
$S2 =  ($S1 | ConvertFrom-JSON )

#Lo recorro con bucle for 
for ($i=0; $i -lt $S2.count; $i++)
{
   #Accedemos a los campos para modificarlos.

   #Modifico primero un espacio por la T
   $S2[$i].fecha = $S2[$i].fecha.replace(" ","T")

   #Y luego añado  .175Z al final
   $S2[$i].fecha = $S2[$i].fecha + ".175Z"
   $S2[$i].fecha = $S2[$i].fecha.replace("/","-")
   $S2[$i].fecha = $S2[$i].fecha.replace(" ","T")
   $S2[$i]."COUNT(incidencia_id)" = $S2[$i]."COUNT(incidencia_id)" -as [int]
}



#Volvemos a convertirlo a JSON

$S3 =  ($S2 | ConvertTo-JSON )

#Modificamos los últimos caracteres necesarios
$S4 = $S3.replace(""",",”""”)
$S5 = $S4.replace(": ",”=”)
$S5
```

¿La duda es como convertir la fecha del formato DDMMYYYY a YYYYMMDD?
Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Comment: Los json no son con ":" enves de "="?

Comment: Si, pero PowerBI me pide que vaya con el "=" en vez de con los ":" ...